# How to fill a Vec with u64::max_value()

Tags: rust

Is there a way in rust to fill a vec it with a range that has for limit `u64::max_value` ?

```
fn main() {
    let vals: Vec<u64> = (2..u64::max_value()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", vals.len());
}
```

compiler throws: `thread 'main' panicked at 'capacity overflow', src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs:777:5`

Comment: what the point ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that your computer has a 64 bits architecture. That means that it can address at most 2^64 bytes (in practice, that's less).

Now, since the size of an `u64` is 8 bytes, you're trying to reserve `8 * 2^64` bytes. Your computer cannot even address such an amount of bytes!

Also, you're trying to allocate several millions of terabytes in the RAM. That's not a reasonable amount of memory.

The line that panics in the std lib is the following:

```
let alloc_size = capacity.checked_mul(elem_size).unwrap_or_else(|| capacity_overflow());
```

It verifies that the capacity (the number of items) multiplied by the size of your element (8 bytes as I said) does not overflow. That's the programmatic way to represent my former reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

No.

`u64::max_value()` is a *huge* number. You don't have that much memory. No one does.

Comment: For reference, an array of u64s from 2 up to u64_max-1 would take up 147,573,952,589,676,412,912 bytes, or 144,115,188,075,855,872 KiB, or 140,737,488,355,328 MiB, or 137,438,953,472 GiB, or 134,217,728‬ TiB, or 131,072‬ PiB, or 128 EiB. It's estimated that all words ever spoken by humans could be stored in less than 5 EiB. 128 EiB was roughly the total data storage capacity of the world in 2004.